# How to subtract column's values from column's values if columns have different quantity of rows (by matching names)

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table like this, DB is ClickHouse:

```
SELECT name, value, timing 
FROM table1 tl1
WHERE
    timing >= '2022-05-23 01:00:00' AND timing <= '2022-05-23 02:00:00'
ORDER BY name, timing 

┌─name─┬─value─┬──────────────timing─┐
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:03 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:05 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:06 │
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:07 │
│ A    │     9 │ 2022-05-23 01:02:01 │
│ A    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:03:21 │
│ B    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:04:23 │
│ B    │     6 │ 2022-05-23 01:05:33 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:06:30 │
│ C    │     8 │ 2022-05-23 01:07:41 │
│ C    │     3 │ 2022-05-23 01:08:44 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:09:50 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

From each "A","B","C" value (first query) I need to subtract a value from the same table, that match min(timing).

With next query, I selected the values ​​that satisfy a condition min(timing) per each unique name.

```
SELECT
    tpl.1 AS name,
    tpl.6 AS value,
    tpl.3 AS timing
FROM
(
    SELECT argMin(tuple(*), timing) AS tpl
    FROM table1 tl 
    WHERE timing >= '2022-05-23 01:00:00' AND timing <= '2022-05-23 02:00:00'
    GROUP BY name
)
ORDER BY name ASC, timing


┌─name─┬─value─┬──────────────timing─┐
│ A    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:03 │
│ B    │     5 │ 2022-05-23 01:04:23 │
│ C    │     7 │ 2022-05-23 01:06:30 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

The resulting values from second query ​​I need to subtract from the original table, by matching the names. This is issue that I can't resolve. My goal is to obtain next table, where from each value "A","B","C" from first query, I subtract a "A","B","C" values (with the lowest timing) from second query.

As result I need a table like this:

```
┌─name─┬─value─┬──────────────timing─┐
│ A    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:03 │
│ A    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:05 │
│ A    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:06 │
│ A    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:01:07 │
│ A    │     4 │ 2022-05-23 01:02:01 │
│ A    │     3 │ 2022-05-23 01:03:21 │
│ B    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:04:23 │
│ B    │     1 │ 2022-05-23 01:05:33 │
│ C    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:06:30 │
│ C    │     1 │ 2022-05-23 01:07:41 │
│ C    │    -4 │ 2022-05-23 01:08:44 │
│ C    │     0 │ 2022-05-23 01:09:50 │
└──────┴───────┴─────────────────────┘
```

I just need to combine my queries, but I don't know how to do this.

Also, second query may be modified to:

```
SELECT name, value  
FROM table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, MIN(timing) AS min_timing
    FROM table1 tl
    WHERE timing >= '2022-05-23 01:00:00' AND timing <= '2022-05-23 02:00:00'
    GROUP BY name
) tbl2
    ON tbl2.name = tbl1.name AND
       tbl2.min_timing = tbl1.timing
WHERE
    timing >= '2022-05-23 01:00:00' AND timing <= '2022-05-23 02:00:00' 
ORDER BY name, timing
```

Comment: This is easier with `FIRST_VALUE` (see my answer). But your approach is also fine, and it seems you just got sidetracked, as you know already how to do that. Your argMin query works, so what keeps you from joining it to the original table? `select tbl1.name, tbl1.value - q.tpl as diff, tbl1.timing from table1 tbl1 join (...) q on q.name = tbl1.name order by tbl1.name, tbl1.timing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the window function `FIRST_VALUE` to get the minimum value per name:

```
SELECT
  name,
  value - FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timing) as diff,
  timing
FROM table1
WHERE timing >= timestamp '2022-05-23 01:00:00'
  AND timing <  timestamp '2022-05-23 02:00:00'
ORDER BY name, timing;
```